How to fix segmentation model producing black segmentation masks?
Apologies in advance for incorrect formatting, I've been kindly sent here after posting my question on StackOverflow.
We're training a segmentation model using Snapchat's template for custom segmentation in Google Colab. We've compiled a dataset for different car parts like wheels and windows, which has been reviewed and seems to be in good shape.
We would like the model to produce an output that can be used as a segmentation mask in Lens Studio, but at this point training the model always produces an almost entirely black image. The IoU does not increase above 0.2, and the loss value seems almost stuck entirely throughout training.
We've tried the following:

Change the training metric to IoU instead of loss
Adjust learning rate, weight decay, factor and patience values
Adjust the batch size and training steps
Adjust the threshold value

However, the images below illustrate our output which is almost entirely consistent across different training loops.


We're not experienced building or adjusting our own machine learning models, so we're at a loss on how to increase the quality of the segmentation output of our model. Our code is provided below, any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""segmentation_training_mix.ipynb

Automatically generated by Colab.

Original file is located at
    https://colab.research.google.com/drive/15nZMptV33q6K3ZE0y_xvBneCU-Oas_Bm

First we need to prepare our work environment and install the necessary Python packages
"""

# Commented out IPython magic to ensure Python compatibility.
# %pip install -q cython==0.29.21 pycocotools # It's needed for installing pycocotools
# %pip install -q numpy opencv-python-headless \
    torch torchvision \
    albumentations tqdm \
    onnx onnxsim
# %pip install torchmetrics
# %pip install -q pydrive

"""# Imports"""

# Commented out IPython magic to ensure Python compatibility.
import os
import random
from pathlib import Path
from urllib.request import urlretrieve, urlcleanup
from zipfile import ZipFile

import albumentations as albm
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pycocotools.coco import COCO
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
from google.colab import files
import shutil

# %config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina'

RANDOM_SEED = 1337
torch.manual_seed(RANDOM_SEED)
torch.cuda.manual_seed(RANDOM_SEED)
np.random.seed(RANDOM_SEED)

# Flip values for slower training speed, but more determenistic results.
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = False
torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = True

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

COCO_CATEGORY = 'windows'  # target category for segmentation

COCO_ANNOTATIONS_PATH = './drive/MyDrive/carar_ML/annotations/carAnnotations.json'
COCO_IMAGES_PATH = './drive/MyDrive/carar_ML/train2017/'

NUM_TRAINING_STEPS = 20000  # number of steps for training, longer is better
VALIDATION_FREQUENCY = 100  # log validation every N steps
BATCH_SIZE = 32  # 64 - number of images per batch
NUM_WORKERS = 4  # number of CPU threads available for image preprocessing

# This controls input and output resolution for the network.
# Lower values lead to worse mask quality, but faster network inference.
# Change carefully.
INPUT_HEIGHT = 256
INPUT_WIDTH = 128

THRESHOLD = 0.15

# This variable below will let this code run on GPU if CUDA device is available.
DEVICE = torch.device('cpu')
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    DEVICE = torch.device('cuda')
    torch.cuda.manual_seed(123)

"""Colab's GPU runtimes don't have enough free drive space to store entire COCO dataset, so we'll have to unpack only the files that we need for training particular category. If you encounter message "Disk is almost full" on Google Colab, please click the "ignore" button."""

def download_file(link, filename):
    if Path(filename).exists():
        return
    progress_bar = tqdm(desc=filename,
                        dynamic_ncols=True, leave=False,
                        mininterval=5, maxinterval=30,
                        unit='KiB', unit_scale=True,
                        unit_divisor=1024)
    def update_progress(count, block_size, total_size):
        if progress_bar.total is None:
            progress_bar.reset(total_size)
        progress_bar.update(count * block_size - progress_bar.n)
    urlretrieve(link, filename, reporthook=update_progress)
    urlcleanup()
    progress_bar.close()


if not os.path.isfile('./drive/MyDrive/carar_ML/train2017.zip'):
    download_file('http://images.cocodataset.org/zips/train2017.zip', 'train2017.zip')

if not os.path.isfile('./annotations_trainval2017.zip'):
    download_file('http://images.cocodataset.org/annotations/annotations_trainval2017.zip',
                  'annotations_trainval2017.zip')
    with ZipFile('./annotations_trainval2017.zip', 'r') as archive:
        archive.extractall()

"""Lets load the images and find all image ids that contain our desired class."""

coco = COCO(COCO_ANNOTATIONS_PATH)
cat_ids = coco.getCatIds(catNms=[COCO_CATEGORY])
img_ids = coco.getImgIds(catIds=cat_ids)

"""We also need some images that don't contain our desired class.
Otherwise the network would always expect to have our object in the input image and will have lots of false positives, like segmenting faces as pizzas.
"""

with ZipFile('./drive/MyDrive/carar_ML/train2017.zip') as archive:
    coco_images_list = archive.namelist()
all_ids = [int(i.split('train2017/')[-1][:-4]) for i in coco_images_list[1:]]
non_class_img_ids = list(set(all_ids) - set(img_ids))
print(all_ids)
print(img_ids)
print(non_class_img_ids)
negative_samples = np.random.choice(non_class_img_ids,
                                    size=len(non_class_img_ids) // 2,
                                    replace=False)
positive_samples = np.random.choice(img_ids,
                                    size=len(img_ids) - (len(img_ids) // 10),
                                    replace=False)
train_img_ids = np.concatenate((positive_samples, negative_samples))
np.random.shuffle(train_img_ids)
val_img_ids = np.array(list(set(img_ids) - set(train_img_ids)))

"""Now we will extract only the images that we need for training, since COCO is pretty large and contains lots of other categories."""

if not os.path.isdir('./drive/MyDrive/carar_ML/train2017'):
    os.mkdir('./drive/MyDrive/carar_ML/train2017')

train_images = [str(i).zfill(6) + '.jpg' for i in train_img_ids]
val_images = [str(i).zfill(6) + '.jpg' for i in val_img_ids]

with ZipFile('./drive/MyDrive/carar_ML/train2017.zip', 'r') as archive:
    for image in tqdm(val_images, dynamic_ncols=True, leave=False):
        archive.extract(image, './')
with ZipFile('./drive/MyDrive/carar_ML/train2017.zip', 'r') as archive:
    for image in tqdm(train_images, dynamic_ncols=True, leave=False):
        archive.extract(image, './')

"""Let's also load an image that we'll use to check the quality of the segmentation while we train the network."""

TEST_IMG = cv2.imread('./drive/MyDrive/carar_ML/train2017/000840.jpg')[:, :, ::-1]

plt.imshow(TEST_IMG);

"""# Model definition

This model is based on Mobilenet V2 https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.04381.
This is a good starting place for general segmentation model, however there were a range of new architectures optimized for mobile inference, including Mobilenet V3 https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.02244.

This model runs on average 12.3ms on iPhone 6S.

Our model will use pretrained weights of Mobilenet V2, however these weights assume the input to be RGB in range [0, 1] and input should be normalized. We will disregard this and just use pretrained weights as good initialization for our network. You can play around and check if using the network from scratch without pretrained weights helps you achieve better segmentation quality.

### Important point regarding input and output ranges
Lens studio feeds the network camera input as RGB images with values in range [0, 255]. This is uncommon in general for neural networks, but in our case we will train the network with this range from scratch, to avoid doing rescaling on network export or import. That's why we need to scale the weights of the first layer – they were trained with normalized values in different range.
"""

# We also need to replace Mobilenet's ReLU6 activations with ReLU.
# There is no noticeable difference in quality, but this will
# allow us to use CoreML for mobile inference on iOS devices.
def replace_relu6_with_relu(model):
    for name, module in reversed(model._modules.items()):
        if len(list(module.children())) > 0:
            model._modules[name] = replace_relu6_with_relu(model=module)
        if isinstance(module, nn.ReLU6):
            model._modules[name] = nn.ReLU()
    return model


class SegmentationNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        mobilenet = torchvision.models.mobilenet_v2(width_mult=0.5)

        # We reuse state dict from mobilenet v2 width width_mult == 1.0.
        # This is not the optimal way to use pretrained models, but in this case
        # it gives us good initialization for faster convergence.
        state_dict = torchvision.models.mobilenet_v2(pretrained=True).state_dict()
        target_dict = mobilenet.state_dict()
        for k in target_dict.keys():
            if len(target_dict[k].size()) == 0:
                continue
            state_dict[k] = state_dict[k][:target_dict[k].size(0)]
            if len(state_dict[k].size()) > 1:
                state_dict[k] = state_dict[k][:, :target_dict[k].size(1)]

        mobilenet.load_state_dict(state_dict)

        weight = mobilenet.features[0][0].weight.detach()
        mobilenet.features[0][0].weight = nn.Parameter(data=weight / 255.)

        mobilenet = replace_relu6_with_relu(mobilenet)

        self.features = mobilenet.features[:-2]
        self.upscale0 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(80, 48, 1, 1, 0, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(48),
            nn.ReLU()
        )
        self.upscale1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(48, 16, 3, 1, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(16),
            nn.ReLU()
        )
        self.upscale2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(16, 16, 3, 1, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(16),
            nn.ReLU()
        )
        self.upscale3 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(16, 8, 3, 1, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(8),
            nn.ReLU()
        )
        self.upscale4 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(8, 4, 3, 1, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(4),
            nn.ReLU()
        )
        self.upscale5 = nn.Conv2d(4, 1, 3, 1, 1, bias=True)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = x
        skip_outs = []
        for i in range(len(self.features)):
            out = self.features[i](out)
            if i in {1, 3, 6, 13}:
                skip_outs.append(out)
        out = self.upscale0(out)
        out = nn.functional.interpolate(out, scale_factor=2, mode='nearest')
        out = self.upscale1(out + skip_outs[3])
        out = nn.functional.interpolate(out, scale_factor=2, mode='nearest')
        out = self.upscale2(out + skip_outs[2])
        out = nn.functional.interpolate(out, scale_factor=2, mode='nearest')
        out = self.upscale3(out + skip_outs[1])
        out = nn.functional.interpolate(out, scale_factor=2, mode='nearest')
        out = self.upscale4(out + skip_outs[0])
        out = nn.functional.interpolate(out, scale_factor=2, mode='nearest')
        out = self.upscale5(out)
        return torch.sigmoid(out)

"""# Dataset

The class below specifies image loading and augmentations to add variety to our dataset and increase network stability to different input conditions.
"""

class CocoDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, image_folder, coco, image_list,
                 category, augmentations):
        self.image_folder = image_folder
        self.coco = coco
        self.image_list = image_list
        self.category = category
        self.augmentations = augmentations

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        image_name = self.image_list[item]
        image_path = os.path.join(self.image_folder,
                                  str(image_name).zfill(6) + '.jpg')
        image = cv2.imread(image_path)[:, :, ::-1]
        ann_ids = coco.getAnnIds(imgIds=image_name, catIds=self.category,
                                 iscrowd=None)
        annotations = coco.loadAnns(ann_ids)
        target = []
        if len(annotations) == 0:
            target = np.zeros((image.shape[0], image.shape[1]))
        else:
            for ann in annotations:
                target.append(coco.annToMask(ann))
        target = np.array(target).sum(axis=0)
        target = np.clip(target, 0, 1).astype('float')
        scaled_width = int(INPUT_HEIGHT * image.shape[1] / image.shape[0])
        image = cv2.resize(image, (scaled_width, INPUT_HEIGHT),
                           interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
        target = cv2.resize(target, (scaled_width, INPUT_HEIGHT),
                            interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
        augmented = self.augmentations(image=image, mask=target)
        image = augmented['image']
        target = augmented['mask']

        image = image.astype('float32')

        return {'image': image.transpose(2, 0, 1),
                'target': target[np.newaxis, :, :].astype('float32')}

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.image_list)

train_augmentations = albm.Compose([
    albm.ShiftScaleRotate(rotate_limit=10),
    albm.PadIfNeeded(min_height=INPUT_HEIGHT, min_width=INPUT_WIDTH,
                     always_apply=True),
    albm.RandomCrop(height=INPUT_HEIGHT, width=INPUT_WIDTH,
                    always_apply=True),
    albm.HueSaturationValue(),
    albm.RandomBrightnessContrast(),
    albm.GaussNoise(),
    albm.MotionBlur(),
    albm.HorizontalFlip()
])
val_augmentations = albm.Compose([
    albm.PadIfNeeded(min_height=INPUT_HEIGHT, min_width=INPUT_WIDTH,
                     always_apply=True),
    albm.Crop(0, 0, INPUT_WIDTH, INPUT_HEIGHT, always_apply=True)
])

train_dataset = CocoDataset(COCO_IMAGES_PATH, coco, train_img_ids,
                            cat_ids, train_augmentations)
val_dataset = CocoDataset(COCO_IMAGES_PATH, coco, val_img_ids,
                          cat_ids, val_augmentations)

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                           num_workers=NUM_WORKERS, drop_last=True,
                                           shuffle=True,
                                           worker_init_fn=lambda _: np.random.seed())
val_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                         num_workers=NUM_WORKERS, drop_last=False,
                                         shuffle=False,
                                         worker_init_fn=lambda _: np.random.seed())

"""# Optimizer setup

Here we set up training and model itself. We'll also set up learning rate scheduler to drop learning rate if our network training platoes.
"""

model = SegmentationNet()
model = model.to(device=DEVICE)
loss = nn.BCELoss()
loss = loss.to(device=DEVICE)

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001, weight_decay=0.0002)  # Adjusted learning rate 0.0001
scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau(optimizer, mode='min', factor=0.15, patience=8, verbose=True)  # Increased patience

"""For metrics we will only check IoU, accuracy and loss value."""

class Metrics():
    def __init__(self, loss_function):
        self.loss_function = loss_function
        self.loss_value = 0
        self.iou = 0
        self.accuracy = 0
        self.batches = 0

    def add_batch(self, prediction, target):
        loss_value = self.loss_function(prediction, target)
        thresholded_prediction = (prediction >= THRESHOLD).to(torch.float32)
        accuracy = (thresholded_prediction ==
                    target).to(torch.float32).mean().item()
        intersection = ((thresholded_prediction == 1) & (target == 1)).sum((2, 3))
        union = ((thresholded_prediction == 1) | (target == 1)).sum((2, 3))
        iou = (intersection.to(torch.float32) /
               (union.to(torch.float32) + 1e-7)).mean().item()
        self.loss_value = (self.loss_value * self.batches + loss_value) / \
                          (self.batches + 1)
        self.iou = (self.iou * self.batches + iou) / (self.batches + 1)
        self.accuracy = (self.accuracy * self.batches + accuracy) / \
                        (self.batches + 1)
        self.batches += 1

    def reset_metrics(self):
        self.loss_value = 0
        self.iou = 0
        self.accuracy = 0
        self.batches = 0

"""This helper function will display image and network output side by side to see the progress during training"""

def show_test_image_quality(model, image):
    model_input = torch.zeros(1, 3, INPUT_HEIGHT, INPUT_WIDTH,
                              dtype=torch.float32, device=DEVICE)
    new_height = int(image.shape[0] * INPUT_WIDTH / image.shape[1])
    resized_image = cv2.resize(image,
                               (INPUT_WIDTH, new_height),
                               interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    resized_image = resized_image.astype('float32')
    model_input[:, :, :new_height, :] = torch.tensor(resized_image.transpose(2, 0, 1))
    model_output = model(model_input)
    output_mask = model_output[0].detach().cpu().numpy().transpose(1, 2, 0)[:new_height]

    output_image = resized_image / 255.
    plot_image = np.zeros((output_image.shape[0], output_image.shape[1] * 3, 3))
    plot_image[:, :INPUT_WIDTH] = output_image
    plot_image[:, INPUT_WIDTH:INPUT_WIDTH * 2] = output_mask
    plot_image[:, INPUT_WIDTH * 2:] = output_image * output_mask

    plt.imshow(plot_image)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()

"""# Train loop"""

metrics = Metrics(loss)

progress = tqdm(desc='Training progress', total=NUM_TRAINING_STEPS,
                dynamic_ncols=True, leave=False)

batch_num = 0
while batch_num < NUM_TRAINING_STEPS:
    train_loss = 0
    model.train()
    bn = 0
    for batch in train_loader:
        batch_num += 1
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        batch['image'] = batch['image'].to(DEVICE)
        batch['target'] = batch['target'].to(DEVICE)

        loss_value = loss(model(batch['image']), batch['target'])
        loss_value.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        train_loss = (train_loss * bn + loss_value.item()) / (bn + 1)
        bn += 1

        # Next two lines make sure we don't update the progress bar too frequently
        if batch_num % int(NUM_TRAINING_STEPS / 100) == 0:
            progress.update(int(NUM_TRAINING_STEPS / 100))

        if batch_num % VALIDATION_FREQUENCY == 0:
            print("[{}] train \t loss: {:.5f}".format(batch_num, train_loss))
            train_loss = 0
            bn = 0

            model.eval()
            for batch_val in val_loader:
                batch_val['image'] = batch_val['image'].to(DEVICE)
                batch_val['target'] = batch_val['target'].to(DEVICE)

                prediction = model(batch_val['image']).detach()

                metrics.add_batch(prediction, batch_val['target'])

            print("[{}] val \t loss: {:.5f}\t IoU: {:.5f}\t accuracy: {:.5f}".format(
                batch_num, metrics.loss_value, metrics.iou, metrics.accuracy))
            scheduler.step(metrics.loss_value)

            show_test_image_quality(model, TEST_IMG)
            metrics.reset_metrics()

            model.train()

        if batch_num >= NUM_TRAINING_STEPS:
            break
progress.close()

"""# Export

### Imporant note regarding Lens Studio input and output ranges

LensStudio sends RGB image to the network input with values in range [0, 255]. Our network is already trained for that, but if you trained the network with other input range you might need to adjust it when you import your ONNX file.

Current network output is in range [0, 1], but again LensStudio needs the output texture to have values in range [0, 255]. That's why we'll use wrapper class for our model that just runs the model and mutiplies output values by 255 to get them to the necessary range.
"""

class ModelForExport(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, model):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = model

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.model(x) * 255

model.eval()
model_for_export = ModelForExport(model)
dummy_input = torch.randn(1, 3, INPUT_HEIGHT, INPUT_WIDTH,
                          dtype=torch.float32, device=DEVICE)
output = model_for_export(dummy_input.detach())
input_names = ["data"]
output_names = ["prob"]
torch.onnx.export(model_for_export, dummy_input,
                  "./car_segmentation.onnx", verbose=False,
                  input_names=input_names, output_names=output_names, opset_version=11)
!onnxsim ./car_segmentation.onnx ./car_segmentation_sim.onnx
# files.download("./" + "car_segmentation_sim.onnx")
drive_path = './drive/MyDrive/carar_ML'  # Adjust the path as needed
shutil.move('./car_segmentation_sim.onnx', drive_path)

Apologies for any issues on this post, I'll gladly provide more information or make adjustments if needed.
